# org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException in HttpPost

Tags: java, android, http-post

I try upload some string to server. When I try upload on server, in string:

```
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I have error org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException. All code:

```
public void sendString(String stringToSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverAddress);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity( new ByteArrayInputStream(stringToSend.getBytes()), stringToSend.length());
        reqEntity.setContentType("application/xml");
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.i("SEND", "not send "+response.getStatusLine());
        }else{
            Log.i("SEND", "send ok "+response.getStatusLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("IOException", e.toString() +" "+ e.getMessage());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Sory I found the answer. If someone will have this error, I fix it this way: 
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity( stringToSend, HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public void sendString(String stringToSend) {

try {
    HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverAddress);
    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity( new ByteArrayInputStream(stringToSend.getBytes()), stringToSend.length());
    reqEntity.setContentType("application/xml");
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.i("SEND", "not send "+response.getStatusLine());
    }else{
        Log.i("SEND", "send ok "+response.getStatusLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("IOException", e.toString() +" "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Comment: In my case, I had some headers with blank or null values. Removing them fixed my issue